# looking for a sample with Angular 4 and more one spring boot application

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a full stack web application (Angular 4 + Spring Boot + Spring Web + Spring Security).
I want add an other spring boot application (micro service) but with the same auth.

**How to share sessions please?**

[image]

For now, here is my configuration of my first Spring Boot application:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/health").hasRole("SUPERUSER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("secret").roles("SUPERUSER");
    }

}
```

**Edit 1:**

I add an other spring boot application (Gateway with my data base) + use JWT between this gateway and other Spring boot applications

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I find a good sample on github [here](https://github.com/mrin9/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security: JWT token for API and session for web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970848/spring-security-jwt-token-for-api-and-session-for-web)

Comment: @kemsky, 
it is easier to down vote than to give an answer !!!!! :(

Comment: I add an other spring boot application (Gateway with my data base) + use JWT between this gateway and other Spring boot applications

Comment: @Andrei Epure, you read the answer of Illia Smolii (JWT) and you put "duplicate post". In my question, I do not write "JWT".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to move from the stateful (with the session on the server-side) to the stateless architecture. In this case, authentication might be implemented using [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: @lllia Smolii, i try with io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt Maven dependancy, thanks