# Prevent session creation when using basic auth in spring security

Tags: spring-security

How can I prevent/avoid the session creation when I request to my RESTful api using basic auth?

My application has a front-end that needs sessions, but some of my others applications communicate with it via the RESTful api. In that cases I need to prevent the session creation because my app has a session management that limit 1 session per user.

My problem today is that this others apps invalidate the active browser session because the other app are using the same user who the browser has used.

Comment: will be better and more organized if you put your solution as a answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a [solution using Multiple HttpSecurity configurations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity). I created 2 security configurations.

My primary now is only applied if a specific HEADER is present and at this configuration the session management is **STATELESS**:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        http.requestMatcher(new RequestMatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
                return request.getHeader(CheckVersionAspect.ESB_VERSION_HEADER) != null ||
                        request.getHeader(CheckVersionAspect.PDV_VERSION_HEADER) != null;
            }
        }).authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .httpBasic()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        //@formatter:on
    }
```

And the second configuration continues with the session management to limit 1 session per user.

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44973699/1470436).